# Problems when create django group by, SUM, COUNT and ouput json

Tags: sql, django-models, group-by

i have problems i create this query in django but, not show "count_resume"

```
SELECT sum(ot.count_find) as count_resume, ot.category_id FROM categoryresume ot GROUP BY ot.year, ot.month, week,ot.category_id order by count_resume desc;


qcats = CategoryResume.objects.filter(year=current_year, month=current_month).annotate(count_resume = Sum('count_find'))

result = serializers.serialize('json', qsources)
```

Thanks for you help.